# How to stop BeautifulSoup from decoding HTML entities into symbols

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I am trying to get all the links on a given website but is stuck with some problems about HTML entities. Here's my code that crawls websites using BeautifulSoup:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
    .
    .

baseRequest = requests.get("https://www.example.com", SOME_HEADER_SETTINGS)
soup = BeautifulSoup(baseRequest.content, "html.parser")
pageLinks = []

for anchor in soup.findAll("a"):
    pageLinks.append(anchor["href"])
    .
    .

print(pageLinks)
```

The code becomes problematic when it sees this kind of element:

```
<a href="./page?id=123&sect=2">Link</a>
```

Instead of printing `["./page?id=123&sect=2"]`, it treats the `&sect` part as an HTML entity and shows this in the console:

```
["./page?id=123§=2"]
```

Is there a solution to preventing the this?

Comment: You're going to need html class to prevent this , import html
print(html.unescape('&pound;682m')) . So during printing add in html.unescape. Let me know if this helps before i post it as an answer

Comment: check my answer

Comment: @FreedomPride html.unescape() doesn't seem to work here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup('<a href="./page?id=123&sect=2">Link</a>', "html.parser")
pageLinks = []

for anchor in soup.findAll("a"):
    pageLinks.append(anchor["href"])


uncoded = ''.join(i for i in pageLinks).encode('utf-8')
decoded = ''.join(map(lambda x: chr(ord(x)),''.join(i for i in pageLinks)))
print('uncoded =',uncoded)
print('decoded =',decoded)
```

output

```
uncoded = b'./page?id=123\xc2\xa7=2'
decoded = ./page?id=123§=2
```

Comment: Thanks! Turning it into a byte string makes it a lot easier to replace the unescaped keyword!